# Can I use controls that are embedded in a vendors wpf exe?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a vendors exe file that I run alongside my own crm application.
I'd like to have the controls from the vendors exe reused in my own application.

Both apps are wpf (prism based).
I don't have access to the vendors code base (of course).

Is there any way I can do this, or am I likely to be howling at the moon?

Regards
Steve

Comment: Have you tried adding the exe as a reference in your project ? What does the VS Object Browser reveal ?

Comment: have you tried dotPeek?

Comment: You may likely to fall into license issues if you start using your vendor's controls in your project. [You paid your vendor to use his control's not to reuse :p ]